# How to carry out compliance for transactions between customers using single compliance server?

Tags: assets, javascript-sdk, stellar-sdk, compliance, server

I have set up an Anchor account and created a custom asset to have customers trade with. I want to set up some compliance for transactions sent from one customer to the other. All customers will be managed by that one Anchor.

Based on the Stellar documentation it provides a guide for setting up a Bridge server which receives the asset transaction on behalf of the customer and communicates with an external compliance server to verify transaction between two financial institutes.

In this case, the Anchor should not be receiving the asset on behalf of a customer but rather when a customer sends a transaction to another customer, the transaction details are reviewed against the Anchor's compliance rules (without the Anchor account having to receive and hold the asset) and once the compliance passes, the transaction is released to the Stellar network and the customers account is credited.

Is it necessary to use the bridge server setup defined by Stellar since the Anchor will not be receiving payments on behalf of the customer?

Transaction flow:

1. Customer A sends a transaction to Customer B of 100 custom_asset.
2. The transaction is sent to the Anchor's API endpoint to process transactions.
3. The transaction is reviewed by the Anchor against its own compliance rules.
4. Once the compliance passes, the Anchor also signs the transaction (multisig) and sends it to the Stellar network.
5. Customer B receives 100 custom_asset in their wallet

Answer (score 0):

why do you need anchor's involvement for such transaction? Both customers A and B should have got authorization from the anchor through trustline to hold the tokens issued by the anchor. You need off-chain way for customers to send the presigned transaction to the anchor for review, if you do need the anchor's involvement for such transaction.

Comment: The FI which controls the anchor will have some compliance rules established for trading of the tokens between its customers eg. possibly a time to the amount of transactions per day. Therefore, the customers sign the transaction and send it to the FI's API. When a transaction is received on the FI's API that's when the compliance check it carried out before the second signature signs the transaction and sends it to the stellar network. Is this compliance check possible using the prebuilt stellar compliance server or is it better to build something custom?